# Why there is no not-nil? in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In clojure I noticed functions with logical opposites like [[if x if-not]  [every? x not-every]].

I wonder why [not-nil?] is not included, is it on purpose or because it is too trivial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `some?` since Clojure 1.6:

```
clojure.core/some?
([x])
Returns true if x is not nil, false otherwise.
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some_q

Answer (score 1):

In Clojure both the values false and nil are falsey (treated as "false") everything else is truthy (treated as "true").

As an example,

```
(if-not nil
        true
        false)
```

evaluates to true, and

```
(if-not false
        true
        false)
```

also evaluates to true. In most cases you should not explicitly check for nil, but rather use the forms that operate on falsey/truthy values.

If you must check for only nil, then you can use [`some?`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some?) and derivates.